# Reputation bar chart display error

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

I am seeing the following bug on the reputation bar chart:

[image: Reputation bar chart duplicaiton]

Comment: Reproduced on FF latest and Chrome latest: http://i.imgur.com/MYvpdNW.jpg

Comment: We see it too... working on it. Thank you.

Comment: I was in the middle of asking this myself. Reproduced in Firefox and Internet Explorer, logged in and logged out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Fix is rolled out now. Thanks for reporting it.

Answer (score 4):

The culprit is

```css
.user-show-new .user-rep-chart-summary {
  width: calc((100% - 30px) / 2);
}
```

Probably, it should be

```css
.user-show-new .user-rep-chart-summary {
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
}
```

Comment: Or even just `width: 100%;`

Comment: Or `width: auto`. But those produce a longer line. Not sure if it's desired.