# Reputation bar chart has additional space on the right

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page

As feedback to the recent fix of the previous [bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314539/reputation-bar-chart-duplication) mentioned, I am now faced with the following case:

[image]

<sup>*Darkened theme for Stack Overflow, it isn't the cause, though.</sup>

Where the space on the right of the reputation bar is more than it should be (or than it was, if I'm not mistaken); this gives a false impression of inactivity, from a reputation aspect, for the 2-3 most recent days.

My version of Chrome is: 46.0.2490.80 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: How wide do you think it should be?

Comment: @TylerH Not wider, but the reputation for the current day was at the very end of the reputation bar as of yesterday. Now it's like I've had two (or 3?) days with no reputation.

Comment: I suspect this is related to the wider page size - the bars might just need to be made proportionally wider, or show more days.